# Prevent multiple instances in webview activity

Tags: android, webview, push-notification

I have a webview activity, in which it's url is updated by a notification service. When a notification is clicked new activity is created everytime to load that changed URL. This can be prevented by adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in manifiest.

If a new activity is created every time when notification is clicked it leads me to change content perfectly. But i want to avoid creating a new activity(or maybe a view is created idk?) for every time notification is clicked. If i add `android:launchMode="singleTask"`in manifest, it gives me a side-effect, i.e if a notification is arrived on existing opened webview activity it does not redirect to changed URL.

Pending notification intent:

```
  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (isMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MiscDisplay.class);
         intent.putExtra("start_url", url);
        intent.setAction("NOTIFICATION_URL_ACTION");
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.extend(new WearableExtender().addAction(message));
        mBuilder.setOngoing(false);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        Notification note = mBuilder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, note);

    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MiscDisplay.class);
        intent.putExtra("start_url", url);
        intent.setAction("NOTIFICATION_URL_ACTION");
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MiscDisplay.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action));
        mBuilder.setOngoing(false);
        Notification note = mBuilder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, note);
```

**What i want?**

I want to avoid creating a new activity each time for when a new notification is clicked.

Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: please paste the pending intent code. which you are using to create notification.

Comment: What's up with changing the link at `webview.loadUrl` everytime the notif is clicked? Does that not load you the required page?

Comment: @Akeshwar no it does not.

Comment: I think you can try to use broadcast to update your webView's URL information.

Comment: @SaurabhKhare added code.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(activityIntent);
```

use this flags before calling your activity
**solution two:**
in manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AL"

public class AL extends Application {
    public static Boolean isActivityRunnig=false;
 @Override
    public void onCreate() 
{
        super.onCreate();
}
```

in your activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AL.isActivityRunnig= true;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AL.isActivityRunnig= false;

    }
```

and when click on notification you can check falg:

```
if(!AL.isActivityRunnig)
   startactivity(new Intent(context,YourActivity.class));
```

Comment: I have added your code, this also results in launching multiple instances of activity whenever new notification is arrived.

Comment: you can define a Static Boolean variable for aware of activity state and set true in onresume() and set false in onPause() method of your activity.and before starting new activity check this variable.notice you should define a single tone class and extend it from Application class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(....this, ....class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("...", ...);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to reload new url, override method onNewIntent() in your webview activity and do something with new params.